# Remover um indeterminado número de "\" numa coluna na base de dados

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-update

O campo `description` na tabela `product` contém HTML gerado pelo [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que trata de fazer escape ao conteúdo:

```html
<table cellpadding=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\" cellspacing=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
...
```

## Problema

O problema aqui é que existiram uma série de acções de copiar/colar por parte do utilizador, onde o CKEditor acabou por aplicar o caractere de escape `\` ao caractere de escape `\` e por aí a fora dando origem ao que pode ser visto em cima.
<sup>*Com cada nova cópia o número de barras foi aumentando...*</sup>

Dado o número de `\` ser diferente em cada lugar e em cada registo presente na tabela, e dada a quantidade de registos, a resolução manual deste assunto é impraticável.

## Pergunta

Como aplicar uma expressão regular a uma consulta de actualização à base de dados, actualizando o campo `description` com o valor que o mesmo contém, mas limpando todas aquelas barras de escape, deixando apenas uma onde mais que uma é encontrado?

Exemplo teórico:

```sql
UPDATE product
SET description = (description - milhões de barras)
WHERE 1
```

---

<sup>Não relevante, mas a questão de copiar e colar limpando caracteres de escape previamente aplicados já se encontra resolvida do lado do PHP. Novos registos não voltam a causar este problema. A questão pretende uma solução em MySQL para lidar com os registos antigos já presentes na base de dados.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

O MySQL não suporta substituição por expressões regulares nativamente (uma das razões por eu preferir o PosgreSQL). Sendo assim, recomendo que instales a lib de UDFs [mysql-udf-regexp.](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) Uma vez feito isso, basta usar a substituição por expressões regulares:

```
UPDATE product
SET description = PREG_REPLACE('\\\\+', '\\', description);
```

A expressão regular `\\\\+` casa com qualquer número de barras invertidas (primeiro parâmetro da função). Como `\` é caractere de escape no MySQL e na expressão regular, é necessário usar quatro `\` para contar como uma na expressão regular. O segundo parâmetro é a string de substituição, que neste caso será `\`. Por fim, o último parâmetro é a coluna na qual a operação será realizada.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode executar a seguinte consulta várias vezes, até ela não alterar mais nenhum registro:

```sql
UPDATE product
SET description = REPLACE(description, '\\\\', '\\')
WHERE description LIKE '%\\\\\\\\%'
```

O MySQL deve indicar que nenhum registro foi alterado com uma mensagem como "Query OK, 0 rows affected". Você também pode verificar que a substituição foi concluída quando a seguinte consulta não retornar nenhum registro:

```sql
SELECT description FROM product
WHERE description LIKE '%\\\\\\\\%'
```

### Explicação

A consulta troca cada par de barras invertidas, `\\`, por uma única, `\`. Assim, em uma primeira execução da consulta, `\\\\` é substituído por `\\`, que, em uma segunda execução é substituído por `\`.

Note que, na expressão `REPLACE(description, '\\\\', '\\')`, a barra invertida é usada como caractere de escape; assim, `'\\\\'` representa duas barras.

A expressão `description LIKE '%\\\\\\\\%'`, busca colunas que contenham duas barras invertidas consecutivas, `\\`. Isso ocorre porque, na expressão `LIKE`, as barras invertidas precisam ser "escapadas" duas vezes. Segundo a [documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> To search for “\”, specify it as “\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar talvez um while em PHP ou alguma outra linguagem com um código similar à este:

```all
WHILE (variable.contains('%\\%')
   variable.replace('\\','\');
```

Answer (score 0):

onde tem duas ou mais de uma barras, troca por uma:

```
$var = '\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\';
echo preg_replace("/\\\+/",'\\',$var);
// retorna: \&quot;\&quot;\&quot;\&quot;\&quot;\
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que você quer "salvar" resultados antigos, então vamos dar um **update** no banco de dados.

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(field, '\\\'', '\'')
WHERE field LIKE '%\\\''
```

Answer (score 0):

Como esse problema é bastante simples, caso você não queira ou não possa instalar uma biblioteca externa para substituições com expressões regulares, eis uma adaptação [dessa função](http://www.nacodes.com/2013/01/29/Create-Function-MySQL-Regex-replace-TRIM-for-MySQL) do Narcodes.

A única coisa que fiz com a função foi substituir os campos `VARCHAR(1000)` por `TEXT` para lidar com strings de qualquer tamanho e remover a chamada à `TRIM`. Substituir os campos `VARCHAR` por `TEXT` tem um custo em termos de *performance*, mas aumenta a flexibilidade da solução:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `regex_replace`(pattern TEXT, replacement TEXT, original TEXT)

RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp TEXT;
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1);
 DECLARE i INT;
 DECLARE j INT;
 DECLARE qbTemp TEXT;

 SET i = 1;
 SET j = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 SET qbTemp = '';

 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN
  loop_label: LOOP
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label; 
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 SET temp = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(temp , CONCAT(replacement,replacement),
   CONCAT(replacement,'#')),CONCAT('#',replacement),''),'#','');
 RETURN temp;
END//
```

Então podemos nos valer da expressão regular do @André:

```sql
UPDATE product
SET description = regex_replace('\\\\+', '\\', description);
```

---

[Exemplo com SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f232a/2)